# Zend_Db_Table UTF-8 Characters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Tables in my database are created with a correct UTF-8 charset like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
...
...
...
...
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci;
```

However, when I use Zend_Db_Table to fetch the data from the table with this method:

```
public function getSingle($id)
{
    $select = $this->select();
    $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id, 'INTEGER');
    $select->where($where);
    return $this->fetchRow($select);
}
```

It returns an object with messed up UTF-8 characters (converted to iso-8859-1 I guess).

When I look in the database through phpmyadmin, it shows up all characters correctly and it also shows correct encoding (UTF-8) so I don't know where's the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

UPDATE:

So I did this and it works:

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $this->configuration = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH
                                               . '/configs/application.ini',
                                               APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT);
    $this->dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory($this->configuration->database);
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($this->dbAdapter);
    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->dbAdapter,
                                      "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Is there some better way?

UPDATE2:

I tried this:

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $this->configuration = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH
                                               . '/configs/application.ini',
                                               APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT);
    $this->dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory($this->configuration->database);
    $this->dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory($this->configuration->database->adapter,
                                        $this->configuration->database->params->toArray()
                                        + array('driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'")));
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($this->dbAdapter);
}
```

And I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in C:\wamp\www\bakalarka\application\Bootstrap.php on line 46
```

Comment: Please see my answer, for another way, which you might find more convenient.

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable to your setup, but I just read some stories ( http://www.google.com/search?q=MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND ) about PHP bugs where `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` is unavailable in some version(s). :( You could try using the concrete value `1002`, but some messages report that as not working either. Or maybe you should upgrade your setup. Not sure if you believe it's worth all the hastle though.

Comment: It seems to be the case, I'm running PHP 5.3.0 though which is very recent release so I don't know. Anyways I will have to execute the "SET NAMES 'utf8'" query for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using MySQL? The only way that I know of to force it to return UTF-8 data is to open the DB connection and run the following query :

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

or, if you are using the mysqli extension:

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

should work as well...

Comment: Yes, I'm suing MySQL. I go try it.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of setting driver_options, you can easily do the following.

Your ini file:

```
db.adapter         = Pdo_Mysql
db.params.host     = localhost
db.params.dbname   = mydb
db.params.username = myuser
db.params.password = mypass
db.params.charset  = UTF8
```

Note last parameter.
Then read your config using Zend_Config_Ini:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('application.ini');
```

And pass database parameters as config subobject:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
```

Comment: Worked for me as well, best solution here IMHO

Answer (score 3):

[Wim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247429/zend-db-table-utf-8-characters/2247460#2247460) is correct. However, there is way to do this without explicitly executing the query, by using the `driver_options` option for the Zend_Db factory method. I assume you use the `pdo_mysql` adapter and that you instantiate it with Zend_Db's factory method.

You can pass an additional set of options to the adapter with this factory method. The option for `pdo_mysql` you are looking for is PDO's `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`.

Here's how it works:

```
$adapterType = 'pdo_mysql';
$adapterConfig = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'yourdb',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'yourpassword',
    // here is where the driver options are defined, as an associative array
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);

$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory( $adapterType, $adapterConfig );
```

As you can see, we're able to utilize PDO's `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` option. You probably understand that this constant is unusable in `.ini` configs. So if you read your db adapter config settings from an `.ini` file you either have to use the concrete value of the constant in the `.ini` file, or append/merge the driver_options array later on to the factory method argument at execution (that's what I do), like so:

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory(
 $configuration->database->adapter,
 $configuration->database->params->toArray() +
        array( 'driver_options' => array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8' ) )
);
```

**EDIT**
I assume this is perfectly possible with only passing one argument to the factory method, like you do in your example, as well. I just accustomed to the habit of passing two arguments to the factory method.